# Stack overflow during a Tkinter Drag and Drop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, drag-and-drop

This little piece of Python code implements a Drag and Drop feature in a Canvas **BUT** when you move an item without releasing it for too long (very quickly actually) a **stack overflow** occurs. Can someone explain why?

```py
from tkinter import *

class Pawn():

    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.oval = canvas.create_oval(x-20, y-20, x+20, y+20, fill='black')
        canvas.tag_bind(self.oval, '<Button1-Motion>', self.move)

    def move(self, event):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = event.x-20, event.y-20, event.x+20, event.y+20
        self.canvas.coords(self.oval, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        self.canvas.update()

class Application(Tk):

    def __init__(self, size):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        canvas = Canvas(self, height=size, width=size)
        canvas.pack(side=TOP)

        Pawn(canvas, 50, 50)
        Pawn(canvas, 100, 50)

Application(400).mainloop()
```

The error message:

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow. Current thread 0x000000011917bdc0 (most recent call first): File 
"/Users/attila/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1704 in call File 
"/Users/attila/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1177 in update File "/Users/attila/Desktop/dnd.py", line 21 in move `
```

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Comment: @Attila I've added the error message to the question. You can edit the question after you have submitted. If there is an important detail you've missed, it is better to put it into the qustion than to the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have the answer to my question: it's useless and redundant to put a `canvas.update` after the `canvas.coords`. There is no more stack overflow without it. Sorry for the quick post. So the right code for the method `move` is just:

```py
def move(self, event):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = event.x-20, event.y-20, event.x+20, event.y+20
    self.canvas.coords(self.oval, x1, y1, x2, y2)
```